# How to convert FILE* to numeric handle in 64 bit system?

Tags: c++, pointers, fopen, embedded-v8

I use embedded JavaScript engine, and I used to pass the result of `fopen()` to JS code as a Number.

```
int numeric_handle = (int)fopen(*P1, "rb");
return Number::New(numeric_handle); // Return to JavaScript
```

But now I need to recompile in 64 bit system, and I get

```
fatal error: cast from pointer to smaller type 'int' loses information
```

Now I am sort of stuck, how do I keep the design of my system but change as little code as possible? I was thinking of having a hash-map, an array that holds FILE* and return an ID in that array. But that will mean extra memory management, extra lookup.

Comment: Is the `::` pure C syntax? I jsut know its meaning from C++

Comment: This is C++, but I stick to old good fopen(),fread() for file IO

Comment: On Linux you can use `fileno`. Visual Studio has the similar `_fileno`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would certainly go with "hide the actual type", in other words, use a `map`, `vector` or some similar type to store the `FILE *`, and pass the `index` or whatever is needed to retrieve the `FILE *` for the calls that need it. That way, it won't matter HOW you open the file (you may later want to use `fstream` and C++, for example, which will be much harder to store as a copy of some sort).

Answer (score 2):

long should be enough, but you can use a byte buffer too

```
FILE *f;
char buffer[sizeof(f)];
memcpy(buffer, &f, sizeof(f));
```

Why do you need such a hack?

Comment: I embedded JavaScript engine and want to use the fopen() in my scripts. There is no pointer type in JavaScript, only numbers or strings.

Comment: Certainly on Windows for instance, long is 4 bytes

Answer (score 1):

Use a pointer sized integer like intptr_t from cstdint.